# How to find newest files with a certain name?

Tags: linux, sorting, date, command-line, find

Suppose I have a directory with many files of the same name in subdirectories (for example, comes up when keeping BibTeX files for multiple academic papers).

What's the best way to find the newest version of a file with a given name?

I've come up with the following command

```
find . -name "someFile" -exec ls -alF {} \;
```

which lists all the files named `someFile` along with their dates, but does not sort them from old to new.

Note that the `-t` option to `ls` can't be used here because it is being run separately for each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the proposed solutions results in the following, pretty clean one:

```
find . -name "someFile" -exec ls -latR {} +
```

which shows all versions of the file, newest first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stat` with `find`:

```
find . -name "someFile" -exec stat -c '%n:%Y' {} + | sort -t : -k2 | cut -d : -f1
```

- `stat` command is printing each filename with time since EPOCH value of file modification time
- `sort` is sorting the output from `stat` using 2nd key (modification time)
- `cut` is just selecting first column (filename)

---

**EDIT:** As per comments below you can use:

```
while IFS=: read -r f t; do
    echo "$f <$(date -d @$t)>"
done < <(find . -name "someFile" -exec stat -c '%N:%Y' '{}' + | sort -t : -k2)
```

**EDIT 2:** On Linux systems you can do:

```
find . -name "someFile" -printf "%p:%T@\n" | sort -t : -k2
```

**Update**:

As per OP. Combining the proposed solutions results in the following, pretty clean one:

```
find . -name "someFile" -exec ls -latR {} +
```

which shows all versions of the file, newest first. This will require gnu find as BSD find doesn't have `-ls` option.

Comment: Works nicely, but would be great to see a human-readable date like how `ls` shows.

Comment: So you want both filename as well as timestamp in output?

Comment: That would be nice, but your answer does achieve what I asked. However `1412571865` is a lot less informative than `Oct  6 01:04`, for example, and helps to show the relative modification times of the files.

Comment: You don't need to exec out to stat, find can tell you the mtime: `find ...  -printf "%p:%T@\n"`

Comment: Yes @glennjackman I know `-printf` is available in `find` but just not available in my BSD `find`. I will update the answer for Linux

Comment: I think the combination of different suggestions that I posted in my answer (just now) is the most succinct. If you want to incorporate that into your answer, I'll delete mine and give you back the answer mark.

Comment: OK sure, I have updated the answer with additional command from yours.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (besides anubhava's) would be to use forward quotes to execute `ls` on the result of `find`, which would allow you to use the `-t` modifier:

```
ls -alFt `find . -name "somefile"`
```

Then, if you're inclined to do so, you can use a series of `cut`, `rev` and `head`s to extract the file name:

```
ls -alFt `find . -name "bla.txt"` | rev | cut -d" " -f1 | rev | head -1
```

Comment: This is nice and clean, but doesn't seem to work when file paths have spaces - the path parts are split up and throw errors. Any easy way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The most recent files (top 20):

```
find . -name someFile\* -type f -exec stat -c "%W %n" -- {} \; | sort -nr | head -n20
```

The most aged files (top 20)

```
find . -name someFile\* -type f -exec stat -c "%W %n" -- {} \; | sort -n | head -n20
```

> Note: You need to install `coreutils` to be able to use `stat` command.

You may use different time flags depending on your needs:

```
%w   time of file birth, human-readable; - if unknown
%W   time of file birth, seconds since Epoch; 0 if unknown
%x   time of last access, human-readable
%X   time of last access, seconds since Epoch
%y   time of last modification, human-readable
%Y   time of last modification, seconds since Epoch
%z   time of last change, human-readable
%Z   time of last change, seconds since Epoch
```

See: `stat --help` for more options.

On BSD/OSX you'll have to check for different parameters, or install GNU `stat` from `coreutils` package.

Answer (score 0):

I always have liked the mnemonic "later"

ls -latr | grep filename

the most recent timestamp of the filename will be on the bottom

Comment: I think you mean `ls -latR`, and that does sort the results, but it does not print the full path :(